# How do I add a class to the element using a directive in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

My functionality is that when the device is landscape it will add a class to the div and when it's portrait that class will get removed.

This is what I have implemented so far -

```
<div [class.landscape]="myclass"></div>
```

And on the code,

```
protected myclass:boolean;

checkLandscape() {
  this.myclass = screen.isLandscape; 
  //I have subscribed to the orientation change which will trigger this method when the orientation changes.
}
```

This works perfectly. But I need this functionality in several other places.

So what I thought I'd do is create a directive for which I will pass the class name and for that class name to get added to that element if the conditions are satisfied.

Expected functionality:

```
<div myClassDirective="myclass"></div>
```

And in the directive

```
addMyClass() {
 // add class if it's landscape.
 // removed class if it's portrait.
}
```

Output:

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

I'm using **Angular 2 RC 4.**
I'm new to Angular so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should try like this 'element.addClass('myDraggable');'

Comment: Or this one as well 'angular.element(element).addClass('myDraggable');'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to use Angular2 bindings to add/remove classes with dynamic names but you can use code like below to do it in an angulary way:

```
class MyClassDirective {
  constructor(private renderer:Renderer, private elRef:ElementRef) {}

  private oldClassName:String;

  @Input() set className(value:String) {
    if(oldClassName) {
      this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, this.oldClassName, false);
    }
    if(value) {
      this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, value, true);
    }
    this.oldClassName = value;
  }
}
```